# How create dynamic (growable) DMG file using terminal in MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, dmg, hdiutil

I want to create dynamic (growable) dmg file. I know sparse bundle works well with dynamic file but i want to create blank dynamic dmg file. I tried the following but did not work. Can anyone help please!:

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Sparse Image` (.sparseimage) rather than a `Sparse Bundle` (.sparsebundle).

```
$ hdiutil create -size <size> -type SPARSE -fs HFS+ <name>
```

So to create `MyDMG.sparseimage` that would hold a maximum of 100 MB you would do:

```
$ hdiutil create -size 100m -type SPARSE -fs HFS+ MyDMG
```

**Additional Information**:

↳ https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5751/10139